# Generating public constructor for a model in EMF

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf

EMF generates classes for models with protected no-argument constructor, is there a way to instruct genmodel to generate constructor as public? The only discussion I saw about this was [this one](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=131683/), but not sure if it was addressed.

Comment: The bug report mentioned in your link seems to be Eclipse bug [184478](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=184478) which is marked fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your .genmodel in a properties editor. Find "Model Class Defaults" group. Change "Public Constructors" to "true".